# Forgot password in django

Tags: python, django, forgot-password

I trying to do forgot password function in my django site.
My settings.py is:

```
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'                        #sample
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
 DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
 SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

my urls.py is:

```
url(r'^user/password/reset/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/reset/done/'},
    name="password_reset"),
url(r'^user/password/reset/done/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
    {'post_reset_redirect' : '/user/password/done/'}),
url(r'^user/password/done/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

I followed [this site](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html),the templates are shown there.
When I entered email id ,it shows that it mailed. But I am not getting any email.

I tried in console :

```
>>> from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
>>> email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Message', to=['example@example.com'])
>>> email.send()
1
```

and I got email..
Help me..

Comment: Can you tell How you configured your `EMAIL_BACKEND` ?

Comment: i dont know. may be the default one..

Comment: Did you give a valid email address to the user you are trying to recover the password for?

Comment: yes.. i used a valid email address

Answer (score 0):

Please check your INBOX of 'email@gmail.com'    email id,  May be there is a new email regarding asking your permission to send email.